# How to use blogger video as iframe (Error 400)

Tags: php, iframe, request, blogger

I have a website where I used videos hosted in blogger as iframe, the code looks like this:

```
<iframe width = "100%" frameborder = "0" src = "https://www.blogger.com/video-play.mp4?=contentID=e6dac2f91a67e518" height = "400"> </ iframe>
```

And it worked very well for years, but currently it displays an error message: Bad Request Error 400.

But now the blogger is requiring a token to watch the videos hosted on the blogger and the link now looks like this:

https://www.blogger.com/video.g?token=AD6v5dx1MyTRLyJapJGZyxcRPsVFDcS3DMkuGAvOi4Nlmo1rB6TnXe0uqWFW9bWCaeGRZLgV2cxbD1J9mS9a1MDzzpIM0LfI0uiPETeMvnWtxb3Zh-WgHAsCADoX_uCktMK-aJ9GNaA

I would like to know how I can do in PHP to get the ID of the video e6dac2f91a67e518 and generate the link with the token, or generate the video using JWplayer.

There is a website that is doing this, but I have no idea how to get started:

https://api.4icdn.com/animesorion.php?contentId=11A8AD764512D4E0DC0ADB278602793DE82625FDD35F76B8F862C9BABF80C51DC3703AA21E745F6E63CABB831FB3D145

Comment: Your demo link can't be reached. I think they used video tag instead of iframe. It's only possible with that. I was tried with iframe but i was failed. But i think it's good to upload the video to youtube and iframe it. Because youtube also provides you money.  And your video is also watchable via direct video link and etc etc.